# Bootstrap angular error message leave space after fading

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've found an example: [Here](https://codepen.io/craigshoemaker/pen/uzjKr). But after the error message fades, the content keeps the space occupied by the message.
Here's my code. In my view:

```
  <div data-ng-show="showError" ng-class="{fade:doFade}" class="alert alert-danger"> {{authmessage}}</div>
```

And in my controller:

```
 $scope.userLogin = function () {
            http.post('/api/login/', $scope.formData).then(function (response) {
                 $rootScope.message = response.config.data.email;
                   $location.url('/Projects');
                }).catch(function(response){
                     $scope.showError = false;
                     $scope.doFade = false;
                     $scope.showError = true;

                     $scope.authmessage = response.data;

                 $timeout(function(){
                      $scope.doFade = true;
                     }, 2500); });
        } ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set $scope.showError to false in $timeout function

```
$timeout(function(){
$scope.doFade = true;
$scope.showError = false;
}, 2500);
```